# Disk quota exceeded; truncate not bringing quota back down

Tags: disk-usage, quota

**Resolved**: See "However" at the end of the question for details.

I've managed to hose my login to a Unix box. I don't have an easy way of contacting the administrator, so I'd like to resolve it myself ideally. I don't have root access (that would be too easy).

Per the title, I've managed to create a large file through an app spamming stdout, which I now can't remove. `rm -f` doesn't work, nor does `cat /dev/null >| $file`, nor `truncate -s 0 $file`. Errors are akin to the following, for everything I've tried.

```
tr08[~]$ cat /dev/null >| wordlist.txt
-bash: wordlist.txt: Disk quota exceeded
```

Output from `quota` is unhelpful:

```
tr08[~]$ quota -v
Disk quotas for user meand (uid 8650):
     Filesystem  blocks   quota   limit   grace   files   quota   limit   grace
tau:/uspac/mc10/m10mr
                       0       0       0               0       0       0
```

I'm at a loss on what to do next. Google only gave me `truncate` and `cat \dev\null`, so any advice or suggestion would be gratefully received.

Output requested in the comments:

```
tr08[~]$ uname -a
Linux tr08.ecs 2.6.30.10-106a.fc11.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Sep 21 11:11:58 BST 2010 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
tr08[~]$ mount | grep /m08ad
tau:/uspac/mc10/m10mr on /auto/complb/m10mr type nfs (rw,nosuid,intr,sloppy,addr=163.1.88.228)
```

**However**: I'm not sure what happened, but when I logged in to get the details Gilles requested in the comments, I tried an `rm`, which worked just fine. `quota -v` is now producing no output, either. I've no idea whether this is due to some admin intervention or some other cunning trickery, but it all appears sorted now.

Comment: What unix variant is this? The filesystem looks like NFS, is this right? Do you know what the filesystem type is on the server, and what OS it's running? If you don't know how to answer these questions, please post the output of `uname -a` and `mount | grep /m10mr`.

Comment: @Gilles: I've added that output, but it's moot now anyway; `rm` suddenly started working.

Answer (score 5):

I don't really know, why the commands you mentioned would fail, but you could try

```
> wordlist.txt
```

This tells the shell to truncate the file to 0 length without spawning another process.